# Baked Procedural Textures Stretched

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-baking

I'm working on a personal project and have reached the shading part. I usually go for procedural setups and never find difficulties, but I needed to bake my textures this time since the model had to be exported in a non-blend file. Nothing scary, so I smart UV projected my model and started baking my textures only to find that on some parts of the mesh, the stretch gets so heavy that all the details are lost (as you can see from these pictures)

[image: Procedural shading]
Procedural shading

[image: Backed textures]
Baked textures

The model is low poly with a subdivision surface modifier applied (only modifier in the stack). I have tried all the possible combinations: saving albedo, roughness, and normal maps in sRGB (then applying them with a Non-Linear color space for the last two) or saving the albedo in sRGB and the others directly in Non-Linear, changing the resolution of the maps up to 8K, changing the render sample count from 2 to 16, decreasing the bake margin size from default 16 px to 4 px, progressively increasing the island margin during the smart UV project, enabling or disabling the subsurface modifier or changing the normals shading (flat, smooth, and auto-smooth) during the bake... after countless attempts, I got no luck. Sometimes I would get better results, sometimes worse, but never anything like the procedural setup.

The only thing I can think of is the island area stretch but if I check in the editor it doesn't look so bad:
[image]
Sure, it could be better but I can't wrap my head around how this could produce such problems. If I had an external texture I wanted to project on these UVs I wouldn't be surprised by the stretch (or the seems), but being the other way around, being a 3D shading that needs to be projected on a 2D square, why would this even matter? Shouldn't the software compensate for the stretch, according to the UVs, while baking the image and produce a 1:1 adaptation of what I see using the procedural nodes?

That's why I think the problem is somewhere else in the process and I need help to identify it because I'm running out of ideas and Google stopped being helpful with it a long while ago.

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: You said that your model has a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, but it doesn't seem that you tried tweaking its UV map settings under *Advanced*. I suggest to remove the modifier and compare the bake with the original procedural material. If they match, then the modifier is the cause of the issue. Please note that the modifier creates new geometry which shows up in the UV map. The new geometry may not work that well with the bake, since the bake is based on the original geometry and UV map.